# NSSortDescriptor which generates ORDER BY `name` = 'bob' DESC?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

In raw SQL it would be simple to sort with all bobs coming first.

How can I do this using a NSFetchedResultsController and NSSortDescriptor?

Comment: What have you tried?  This would be a trivial sort descriptor, which leads me to believe you haven't even tried.

Comment: It is not a trivial sort descriptor, if you take into account, that he wants to sort "bob"s first, even there are "amin"s in the data base.

Comment: Avi it's definitely not a trivial sort descriptor :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found to this is kind of problem is to just add an extra field to help with the FRC. ie `isBob` which gets updated whenever the name is set.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you cannot do that with `NSSortDescriptor`, because this is for key-value sorting and does not support expressions.

However, it could work with the help of `NSFetchRequest`. Set the result type of the fetch request to dictionary

```
fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
```

Then you can set the properties to fetch to the properties you want plus add a expression for computed properties:

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"name=='bob'"];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [NSExpressionDescription new];
expressionDescription.name = "isCalledBob";
expressionDescription.expression = expression;
expressionDescription.resultType = NSBooleanAttributeType;

[fetchRequest propertiesToFetch:@[…, expressionDescription];
```

Then you can use `NSSortDescriptor` on the key `isCalledBob`.

With this you get dictionaries instead of managed objects.

Typed in Safari, did not test it, my kid wakes up in some minutes.

Comment: NSFetchedResultsController is a requirement though, otherwise I could do this with a block comparator or just array sort after fetching.

Comment: Yes, you could do that. But accessing the properties for doing so,would cause (property) fault-ins on all objects. In such a case I would prefer to do two fetches, one for bob and one for non-bob and add the result arrays. – If it is possible.